# How to get a Jewish/English event calendar on a page in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, calendar, plugin-events-calendar

What I need is an event calendar to display both the english and Jewish dates, but have it be based on the hebrew date. With this people could input the date of an anniversary and have it reappear every year on the hebrew date and just show what date that would translate to in the english calendar.

I've seen this calendar http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-calendar/, which is perfect, only it doesn't have the Jewish dates.

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to rip apart the plug-in using details from [here](http://www.ziporah-greve.net/prog/jewish-php.html), perhaps?

Comment: thanks! but i'm definitely not that capable lol, i was looking for something more towards an actual plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hebrew-events-calendar/

Comment: any chance you'd update this plugin? It looks like it is exactly what I'm looking for